# Kalman filter by hand

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

I am now learning the Kalman filter and wants to implement it by hand to understand it better. To be specific I want to first simulate a sequence of data by
$$
\dot x=Ax+Bw\\
y=Cx+Dv,\\
E[x(0)]=0,E[x(0)x'(0)]=P_0,
$$
where $w,v$ are white noise processes with unit variance. Then I need to construct the Kalman filter by
$$
\dot{\hat x}=A\hat x+QC'(y-C\hat x), \hat x(0)=0
$$
where $Q$ solves the ricatti differential equation
$$
\dot Q=AQ+QA'-QC'CQ+C'C,Q(0)=P_0.
$$
 I have two questions:

1. How do I generate the sequence of data governed by a differential equation?
2. How do I solve the ricatti differential equation?

I know this post shows no effort, but I am new to mathematica and have no idea where to start (especially that I cannot generate the data needed, which stops me from any progress). Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If you have version 8 or higher, look up [`RicattiSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RiccatiSolve.html), [`KalmanEstimator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KalmanEstimator.html) and the general [guide to control systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ControlSystems.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Regarding 1. you could use `NestList`.

Comment: A pre-v9 related Wolfram Library Archive entry: [Kalman Filter](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4799/).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of implementing a 2D Kalman filter for a constant velocity model.

The state vector contains the 2D position in px, py and the 2D velocity in vx, vy:

```
{px,py,vx,vy}
```

Since we are using a constant velocity model, the state transition matrix is

```
F[dt_] := {{1, 0, dt, 0}, {0, 1, 0, dt}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

where `dt` is the time step.

For the meaurement, we can measure the 2D position `{px,py}`, so the measurement matrix is

```
H = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Assuming there the accelerations as our process noise, and the process noise covariant matrix is

```
Q[dt_] := {{dt^4/4 σx^2, 0, dt^3/2 σx^2, 0}, {0, 
    dt^4/4 σy^2, 0, dt^3/2 σy^2}, {dt^3/2 σx^2, 
    0, dt^2 σx^2, 0}, {0, dt^3/2 σy^2, 0, 
    dt^2 σy^2}}
```

The measurement noise covariant matrix is

```
R = {{2, 0}, {0, 2}};
```

We take use the [Udacity dataset](https://github.com/xslittlegrass/CarND-Extended-Kalman-Filter/tree/master/data) as an example

```
ls = Select[
    Import["sample-laser-radar-measurement-data-1.txt",
      "Table"], #[[1]] == "L" &][[All, 2 ;; 4]];
```

We set the our initial state and covariant matrix:

```
x = {ls[[1, 1]], ls[[1, 2]], 0, 0};
t = ls[[1, 3]];
P = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1000, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1000}};
```

data = Rest@ls;

Now we can apply the Kalman filter algorithm repeatly

```
kal = Table[
   dt = (m[[3]] - t)/1000000.0;
   t = m[[3]];
   (*===predict update===*)
   x = F[dt].x;
   P = F[dt].P.Transpose[F[dt]] + Q[dt];
   (*====measurement update====*)
   y = m[[1 ;; 2]] - H.x;
   S = H.P.Transpose[H] + R;
   K = P.Transpose[H].Inverse[S];
   x = x + K.y;
   P = (IdentityMatrix[4] - K.H).P;
   x
   , {m, data}];
```

And visualize the output

```
ListPlot[kal[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the noise covariant matrix be symmetric and p.d.?

Comment: @anderstood Sorry that's a typo. Thanks!